# How to explore more about the APT provided in the Firefox Add-on SDK (jpm)?

Tags: javascript, api, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, add-on

I am presently working on an add-on that processes the text selection made by the user. For details I referred to [Selection API Documentation - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/selection) and found the method to start logging the text selected by the user at console.

But steps that need to be done to stop the process of this selection logging is not described. Thus I *need help to know how to stop the selection logging at console and more about this API* but am unable to find any relevant resource to do the same.

The code to initiate selection is as follows :-

```
var selection = require("sdk/selection");
function myListener() {
  if (selection.text)
    console.log(selection.text);
}
selection.on('select', myListener);
```

*Need to stop Logging without restarting the browser*